# Плавная анимация ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, анимация, progress-bar

У меня есть ProgressBar

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При создании анимации прогресса получается дёрганая анимация. Как сделать её плавной?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (time >= 0){
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        timeProgress.setProgress(time);
                        timeText.setText(String.valueOf(time));
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                time--;
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: У вас задержка в 1 секунду. Это очень много. Попробуйте снизить её до 250 мс или даже до 100 мс.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, у меня специально отсчёт в секундах

Comment: Попробуйте что-то из этих ответов: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8035682/animate-progressbar-update-in-android

Comment: Действительно, задержку нужно уменьшить. Что касается секунд можно ввести промежуточную переменную, которая каждые 100 мс будет увеличиваться на 100.
И если она >= 1000 то timeText.setText(String.valueOf(time));
Ну и затем обнулить...

Answer (score 0):

1. Ещё один способ сделать ProgressBar в xml файле:

   ```
       <ProgressBar
           android:id="@+id/progress"
           android:layout_width="150dp"
           android:layout_height="150dp"
           android:max="150"
           android:progress="50"
           />
   ```
2. В activity задаем:

   ```
       ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);
       progressBar.setProgress(50);
   ```